# How to add the node settings "Exclude node title" to a field group?

Tags: 8, forms

Since the module does not provide an entry in the manage form settings, how to move "Exclude node title" to a field group in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `form_alter` function:

```
  if (isset($form['exclude_node_title']) && isset($form['title']) && isset($form['#group_children']['title'])) {
    $form['#group_children']['exclude_node_title'] = $form['#group_children']['title'];
  }
```

this will move the exclude title into the same group as title is in